# Как вывести две младшие цифры с числа?

Tags: c, числа

```
printf_s("\n %d", (a >= b ? int(a + 0.5) : int(b + 0.5) ));
```

Как сделать так, чтоб с числа, к примеру, 1234.56 выводилось 12?

Comment: Это как раз две старшие цифры :) А что выводить для 3.1416? или 0.0001567?

Comment: мне нужно 4 значное число
но к вашему примеру ,то 3 и 0.
Так то с числа 987654321 мне нужны только 98

Comment: Если вы заранее **точно знаете, что число четырехзначное** - `printf("%d",int(a)/100);`

Comment: Что такое `a`, что такое `b`? И какое отношение они имеют к вопросу? При чем здесь вообще этот код?

Answer (score 2):

> как сделать так,что б с числа,к примеру, 1234.56 выводилось 12?

Как-то так:

```
double x = 1234.56; //< число
int num = 2;        //< количество старших цифр
printf("%d", (int)x / pow(10, (int)log10(x) + 1 - num) )
```

Выводит две старшие значащие цифры в десятичной записи числа. С математикой предлагаю разобраться самостоятельно.